# Is it possible to design a strongly stable linear multistep method of order 7 which has stiff decay

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm studying for a test and I'd like to know is it possible to design a strongly stable linear multistep method of order 7 which has stiff decay. I have no clue to verify the claim. Can anyone give me a hint?  Thanks for your time.